# Update multiple rows in Database Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to update multiple rows. Here is my controller file:

```
$ids = [$request->get('com_id')];
$name = [$request->get('com_name')];
$stat = [$request->get('com_status')];
$now = Carbon::now();
$count = count($ids);
$thiss=$request->validate(
    ['com_name' => 'required',
    'com_status' => 'required'
]);
// $i=0;
for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) { 
    $companies = companies::find($ids[$i][0]);
    companies::where('id',$ids[$i][0])
    ->update(['company_name' => $name[$i][0],
    'status' =>  $stat[$i][0]
]);
```

but in my code, Just the 1st row is being updated. what can I do for updating multiple rows with array index number?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `id` from a two dimensional array and you are initializing the `$ids` variable like `$ids = [$request->get('com_id')];`. Please first check that you have all the ids in the `$ids` array. if that is alright then any of the following code should work,

```
// #1
companies::where('id', $ids[$i][0])
            ->update([
                'company_name' => $name[$i][0],
                'status' =>  $stat[$i][0]
            ]);

// #2
$company = companies::find($ids[$i][0]);
$company->company_name = $name[$i][0];
$company->status = $stat[$i][0];
$company->save();
```

You should follow the doc to for updating, please look into the https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates and you may find more details.